# GunDB peers option

Tags: gun

I'm not sure I understand how to configure the *gunDB* servers in the constructor. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
var gunOptions = {
  file: 'data.json',
  peers: ['host1.com','host2.com']
}
bucket = new gun(gunOptions);
```

When I do this I get lots of errors that look like this:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
>       at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:180:21)
>       at success (/home/ubuntu/lib/ls/start.ls:88:7)
>       at Gun. (/home/ubuntu/lib/ls/start.ls:204:7)
>       at wcb (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/gun/gun.js:640:18)
>       at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/gun/lib/wsp.js:247:7
>       at r.ws.cbs.(anonymous function) (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/gun/gun.js:1387:6)
>       at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/gun/gun.js:1417:86)
>       at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:418:14)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

However... When I initialize gun like this it works great:

```
bucket = new gun(['host1.com','host2.com']);
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance. ☺

Comment: This looks like a bug. I was not able to recreate it with a quick copy of your code, but I bet I can with some more effort later. Currently out of the country though so I'll try this again when I get back in a week. Out of curiosity, if you do `new Gun().opt(gunOptions)` does that work?

Comment: Good idea. Will test that out and report back...

Comment: Ok... I'm seeing the same issue with that as well.

Comment: would you mind posting a more complete example that caused the error you are seeing? Just got back and would like to get this fixed for you, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: tagging you again, hopefully it'll notify you. Would love to get this fixed for you, if I could get more example code to replicate what is going on.